# Usage of standardEndpoints

Tags: wcf

I am trying to use standardEndpoints in my wcf service as shown below. I am getting 'serviceHostingEnvironment has invalid child element' error.

Any ideas?

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
  <standardEndpoints>
    <webscriptendpoint>
      <standardendpoint crossdomainscriptaccessenabled="true">
      </standardendpoint>
    </webscriptendpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<standardEndpoints>` is a child of `<system.serviceModel>`, not `<serviceHostingEnvironment>` You need something like the config below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <standardEndpoints>
    <webscriptendpoint>
      <standardendpoint crossdomainscriptaccessenabled="true">
      </standardendpoint>
    </webscriptendpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```